# Replace \ with string.empty is not working

Tags: c#, str-replace

I am using Aspose.Words to convert a Word document to HTML and finally into a string containing all the HTML for the document.

What I am having trouble with is replacing the `"\"`.

Here is the string I get from the document:

```
htmlString  "<html><head><meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\" /><meta http-equiv=\"Content-Style-Type\" content=\"text/css\" /><meta name=\"generator\" content=\"Aspose.Words for .NET 13.7.0.0\" /><title></title></head><body><div><p style=\"font-size:12pt; line-height:115%; margin:0pt 0pt 10pt\"><span style=\"color:#ff0000; font-family:Calibri; font-size:12pt; font-weight:bold\">Evaluation Only. Created with Aspose.Words. Copyright 2003-2011 Aspose Pty Ltd.</span></p><h2 style=\"font-size:13pt; line-height:115%; margin:10pt 0pt 0pt; page-break-after:avoid; page-break-inside:avoid\"><span style=\"color:#4f81bd; font-family:Cambria; font-size:13pt; font-weight:bold\">This is a header</span></h2><p style=\"font-size:11pt; line-height:115%; margin:0pt 0pt 10pt\"><span style=\"font-family:Calibri; font-size:11pt\">&#xa0;</span></p><p style=\"font-size:11pt; line-height:115%; margin:0pt 0pt 10pt\"><span style=\"font-family:Calibri; font-size:11pt\">Look at my awesome bulleted list.</span></p><p style=\"font-size:11pt; line-height:115%; margin:0pt 0pt 10pt\"><span style=\"font-family:Calibri; font-size:11pt\">&#xa0;</span></p><p style=\"font-size:11pt; line-height:115%; margin:0pt 0pt 0pt 18pt; text-indent:-18pt\"><span style=\"font-family:Calibri; font-size:11pt\">1)</span><span style=\"font:7.0pt 'Times New Roman'\">&#xa0;&#xa0;&#xa0;&#xa0;&#xa0; </span><span style=\"font-family:Calibri; font-size:11pt\">Option 1</span></p><p style=\"font-size:11pt; line-height:115%; margin:0pt 0pt 0pt 36pt; text-indent:-18pt\"><span style=\"font-family:Calibri; font-size:11pt\">a)</span><span style=\"font:7.0pt 'Times New Roman'\">&#xa0;&#xa0;&#xa0;&#xa0;&#xa0; </span><span style=\"font-family:Calibri; font-size:11pt\">Sup Option A</span></p><p style=\"font-size:11pt; line-height:115%; margin:0pt 0pt 0pt 36pt; text-indent:-18pt\"><span style=\"font-family:Calibri; font-size:11pt\">b)</span><span style=\"font:7.0pt 'Times New Roman'\">&#xa0;&#xa0;&#xa0;&#xa0;&#xa0; </span><span style=\"font-family:Calibri; font-size:11pt\">Sub Option B</span></p><p style=\"font-size:11pt; line-height:115%; margin:0pt 0pt 0pt 36pt; text-indent:-18pt\"><span style=\"font-family:Calibri; font-size:11pt\">c)</span><span style=\"font:7.0pt 'Times New Roman'\">&#xa0;&#xa0;&#xa0;&#xa0;&#xa0;&#xa0; </span><span style=\"font-family:Calibri; font-size:11pt\">Sub Option C</span></p><p style=\"font-size:11pt; line-height:115%; margin:0pt 0pt 0pt 18pt; text-indent:-18pt\"><span style=\"font-family:Calibri; font-size:11pt\">2)</span><span style=\"font:7.0pt 'Times New Roman'\">&#xa0;&#xa0;&#xa0;&#xa0;&#xa0; </span><span style=\"font-family:Calibri; font-size:11pt\">Option 2</span></p><p style=\"font-size:11pt; line-height:115%; margin:0pt 0pt 0pt 36pt; text-indent:-18pt\"><span style=\"font-family:Calibri; font-size:11pt\">a)</span><span style=\"font:7.0pt 'Times New Roman'\">&#xa0;&#xa0;&#xa0;&#xa0;&#xa0; </span><span style=\"font-family:Calibri; font-size:11pt\">Sub Option A</span></p><p style=\"font-size:11pt; line-height:115%; margin:0pt 0pt 0pt 54pt; text-indent:-18pt\"><span style=\"font-family:Calibri; font-size:11pt\">i)</span><span style=\"font:7.0pt 'Times New Roman'\">&#xa0;&#xa0;&#xa0;&#xa0;&#xa0;&#xa0;&#xa0; </span><span style=\"font-family:Calibri; font-size:11pt\">Sub </span><span style=\"font-family:Calibri; font-size:11pt\">Sub</span><span style=\"font-family:Calibri; font-size:11pt\"> Option </span><span style=\"font-family:Calibri; font-size:11pt\">i</span></p><p style=\"font-size:11pt; line-height:115%; margin:0pt 0pt 0pt 36pt; text-indent:-18pt\"><span style=\"font-family:Calibri; font-size:11pt\">b)</span><span style=\"font:7.0pt 'Times New Roman'\">&#xa0;&#xa0;&#xa0;&#xa0;&#xa0; </span><span style=\"font-family:Calibri; font-size:11pt\">Sub Option B</span></p><p style=\"font-size:11pt; line-height:115%; margin:0pt 0pt 0pt 54pt; text-indent:-18pt\"><span style=\"font-family:Calibri; font-size:11pt\">i)</span><span style=\"font:7.0pt 'Times New Roman'\">&#xa0;&#xa0;&#xa0;&#xa0;&#xa0;&#xa0;&#xa0; </span><span style=\"font-family:Calibri; font-size:11pt\">Sub </span><span style=\"font-family:Calibri; font-size:11pt\">Sub</span><span style=\"font-family:Calibri; font-size:11pt\"> Option </span><span style=\"font-family:Calibri; font-size:11pt\">i</span></p><p style=\"font-size:11pt; line-height:115%; margin:0pt 0pt 10pt 54pt; text-indent:-18pt\"><span style=\"font-family:Calibri; font-size:11pt\">ii)</span><span style=\"font:7.0pt 'Times New Roman'\">&#xa0;&#xa0;&#xa0;&#xa0;&#xa0;&#xa0; </span><span style=\"font-family:Calibri; font-size:11pt\">Sub </span><span style=\"font-family:Calibri; font-size:11pt\">Sub</span><span style=\"font-family:Calibri; font-size:11pt\"> Option ii</span></p><p style=\"font-size:11pt; line-height:115%; margin:0pt 0pt 10pt\"><span style=\"font-family:Calibri; font-size:11pt\">&#xa0;</span></p><p style=\"border-bottom-color:#4f81bd; border-bottom-style:solid; border-bottom-width:0.5pt; font-size:11pt; line-height:115%; margin:10pt 46.8pt 14pt; padding-bottom:4pt\"><span style=\"color:#4f81bd; font-family:Calibri; font-size:11pt; font-style:italic; font-weight:bold\">This is another heading</span></p></div></body></html>"   string
```

As you can see it has a whole bunch of =\" I need to remove all of the \'s and replace it with String.Empty.

Here is the code I am using:

```
string htmlString = doc.ToString(SaveFormat.Html);
string text = htmlString.ToString().Replace(@"\", string.Empty);
```

However when I hover over `text` or add a watch for `text` the entire string still displays all of the `\'s`.  What am I doing wrong here?

Here is the watch value for text:

```
text    "<html><head><meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\" /><meta http-equiv=\"Content-Style-Type\" content=\"text/css\" /><meta name=\"generator\" content=\"Aspose.Words for .NET 13.7.0.0\" /><title></title></head><body><div><p style=\"font-size:12pt; line-height:115%; margin:0pt 0pt 10pt\"><span style=\"color:#ff0000; font-family:Calibri; font-size:12pt; font-weight:bold\">Evaluation Only. Created with Aspose.Words. Copyright 2003-2011 Aspose Pty Ltd.</span></p><h2 style=\"font-size:13pt; line-height:115%; margin:10pt 0pt 0pt; page-break-after:avoid; page-break-inside:avoid\"><span style=\"color:#4f81bd; font-family:Cambria; font-size:13pt; font-weight:bold\">This is a header</span></h2><p style=\"font-size:11pt; line-height:115%; margin:0pt 0pt 10pt\"><span style=\"font-family:Calibri; font-size:11pt\">&#xa0;</span></p><p style=\"font-size:11pt; line-height:115%; margin:0pt 0pt 10pt\"><span style=\"font-family:Calibri; font-size:11pt\">Look at my awesome bulleted list.</span></p><p style=\"font-size:11pt; line-height:115%; margin:0pt 0pt 10pt\"><span style=\"font-family:Calibri; font-size:11pt\">&#xa0;</span></p><p style=\"font-size:11pt; line-height:115%; margin:0pt 0pt 0pt 18pt; text-indent:-18pt\"><span style=\"font-family:Calibri; font-size:11pt\">1)</span><span style=\"font:7.0pt 'Times New Roman'\">&#xa0;&#xa0;&#xa0;&#xa0;&#xa0; </span><span style=\"font-family:Calibri; font-size:11pt\">Option 1</span></p><p style=\"font-size:11pt; line-height:115%; margin:0pt 0pt 0pt 36pt; text-indent:-18pt\"><span style=\"font-family:Calibri; font-size:11pt\">a)</span><span style=\"font:7.0pt 'Times New Roman'\">&#xa0;&#xa0;&#xa0;&#xa0;&#xa0; </span><span style=\"font-family:Calibri; font-size:11pt\">Sup Option A</span></p><p style=\"font-size:11pt; line-height:115%; margin:0pt 0pt 0pt 36pt; text-indent:-18pt\"><span style=\"font-family:Calibri; font-size:11pt\">b)</span><span style=\"font:7.0pt 'Times New Roman'\">&#xa0;&#xa0;&#xa0;&#xa0;&#xa0; </span><span style=\"font-family:Calibri; font-size:11pt\">Sub Option B</span></p><p style=\"font-size:11pt; line-height:115%; margin:0pt 0pt 0pt 36pt; text-indent:-18pt\"><span style=\"font-family:Calibri; font-size:11pt\">c)</span><span style=\"font:7.0pt 'Times New Roman'\">&#xa0;&#xa0;&#xa0;&#xa0;&#xa0;&#xa0; </span><span style=\"font-family:Calibri; font-size:11pt\">Sub Option C</span></p><p style=\"font-size:11pt; line-height:115%; margin:0pt 0pt 0pt 18pt; text-indent:-18pt\"><span style=\"font-family:Calibri; font-size:11pt\">2)</span><span style=\"font:7.0pt 'Times New Roman'\">&#xa0;&#xa0;&#xa0;&#xa0;&#xa0; </span><span style=\"font-family:Calibri; font-size:11pt\">Option 2</span></p><p style=\"font-size:11pt; line-height:115%; margin:0pt 0pt 0pt 36pt; text-indent:-18pt\"><span style=\"font-family:Calibri; font-size:11pt\">a)</span><span style=\"font:7.0pt 'Times New Roman'\">&#xa0;&#xa0;&#xa0;&#xa0;&#xa0; </span><span style=\"font-family:Calibri; font-size:11pt\">Sub Option A</span></p><p style=\"font-size:11pt; line-height:115%; margin:0pt 0pt 0pt 54pt; text-indent:-18pt\"><span style=\"font-family:Calibri; font-size:11pt\">i)</span><span style=\"font:7.0pt 'Times New Roman'\">&#xa0;&#xa0;&#xa0;&#xa0;&#xa0;&#xa0;&#xa0; </span><span style=\"font-family:Calibri; font-size:11pt\">Sub </span><span style=\"font-family:Calibri; font-size:11pt\">Sub</span><span style=\"font-family:Calibri; font-size:11pt\"> Option </span><span style=\"font-family:Calibri; font-size:11pt\">i</span></p><p style=\"font-size:11pt; line-height:115%; margin:0pt 0pt 0pt 36pt; text-indent:-18pt\"><span style=\"font-family:Calibri; font-size:11pt\">b)</span><span style=\"font:7.0pt 'Times New Roman'\">&#xa0;&#xa0;&#xa0;&#xa0;&#xa0; </span><span style=\"font-family:Calibri; font-size:11pt\">Sub Option B</span></p><p style=\"font-size:11pt; line-height:115%; margin:0pt 0pt 0pt 54pt; text-indent:-18pt\"><span style=\"font-family:Calibri; font-size:11pt\">i)</span><span style=\"font:7.0pt 'Times New Roman'\">&#xa0;&#xa0;&#xa0;&#xa0;&#xa0;&#xa0;&#xa0; </span><span style=\"font-family:Calibri; font-size:11pt\">Sub </span><span style=\"font-family:Calibri; font-size:11pt\">Sub</span><span style=\"font-family:Calibri; font-size:11pt\"> Option </span><span style=\"font-family:Calibri; font-size:11pt\">i</span></p><p style=\"font-size:11pt; line-height:115%; margin:0pt 0pt 10pt 54pt; text-indent:-18pt\"><span style=\"font-family:Calibri; font-size:11pt\">ii)</span><span style=\"font:7.0pt 'Times New Roman'\">&#xa0;&#xa0;&#xa0;&#xa0;&#xa0;&#xa0; </span><span style=\"font-family:Calibri; font-size:11pt\">Sub </span><span style=\"font-family:Calibri; font-size:11pt\">Sub</span><span style=\"font-family:Calibri; font-size:11pt\"> Option ii</span></p><p style=\"font-size:11pt; line-height:115%; margin:0pt 0pt 10pt\"><span style=\"font-family:Calibri; font-size:11pt\">&#xa0;</span></p><p style=\"border-bottom-color:#4f81bd; border-bottom-style:solid; border-bottom-width:0.5pt; font-size:11pt; line-height:115%; margin:10pt 46.8pt 14pt; padding-bottom:4pt\"><span style=\"color:#4f81bd; font-family:Calibri; font-size:11pt; font-style:italic; font-weight:bold\">This is another heading</span></p></div></body></html>"   string
```

Comment: `Here is the string I get from the document:`. No it is what you see in **debugger**

Comment: @I4V Thanks for that.  I need more sleep. :)

Answer (score 1):

Those aren't actually in the string.

The debugger is showing a string literal for the string, including escape characters.

To see the raw value of the string, use the visualizer (the button on the left)

Answer (score 1):

The `\`s aren't actually there. It's just the display showing you that the `"` isn't the end of the string's contents

Answer (score 1):

> However when I hover over text or add a watch for text the entire string still displays all of the \'s. What am I doing wrong here?

This is just a matter of how the debugger displays values.  The actual text is:

```
<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type"
```

But the debugger escapes the quotes with `\"`

Answer (score 1):

The reason is because it is showing you the string value representation of that string...  In strings, to display the double quote character, you first have to escape it with the \ char.  If you output it to the console you shouldn't see the escape ch